# C++ macro defined in Eclipse is not used during build

Tags: eclipse, c-preprocessor

I'm trying OpenFrameworks. In the generated code, there is this in the Makefile:

```
# make sure the the OF_ROOT location is defined
ifndef OF_ROOT
    OF_ROOT=../../..
endif
```

This path is wrong. I *could* fix it in the code or in the `config.make` file, but I'd rather set this as a variable in Eclipse, so that the code I make can be more easily shared with other members of my team.

I've tried for a couple of hours now a variation of the following: I went to  **Project settings->C/C++ General->Path and Symbols-># Symbols** and in **GNU C** *and* in **GNU C++**, I added a definition for `OF_ROOT` with the correct path.

No matter what I do, the in-file definition is used. I know because when I change it from `../../..` to something else, I see that reflected in the build attempt.

I tried changing **Project settings->C/C++ General->Indexer->Build configuration for the index** to "Use active build for the configuration", but it didn't change anything. Also, I am sure that the build configuration I'm changing is in fact the active one. If it weren't, other problems with the build would be visible.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a day fighting with OpenFrameworks, the answer became clear: the make system of OpenFrameworks completely ignores all of Eclipse's settings. Completely. Every change has to be made in the `config.make` file. Not just the macros, but literally everything that affects the compiler. On the plus side, I'm not much better acquainted with Makefiles.